# How to run Java benchmark on remote machine

Tags: java, benchmarking, jmh

I have jmh set locally on my machine. I can produce the benchmark jar and successfully run my benchmark test. The issue is that I have other processes running on my machine and would like to run it a setting where there's no "interference" from other running processes. I have access to a server that i really, I would want my benchmark jar. Is there a way to install jmh on the remote machine and run my benchmarking test? There's no access to a UI or IDE so everything has to be from the command line.

Comment: Depending on libraries, it might be possible to use X11 remote display over ssh, or in an X11vnc X server you access via VNC.  Or maybe it's easy to set up JMH for command line use, IDK, I'm just here for the benchmarking tag, not java.

Comment: You should be able to do a command line install of Java, jmh and your code on the remote machine.  Obviously, we can give you a recipe ... because you haven't given enough details of the local and remote machines; e.g. operating systems, how much access you have, what version of java you need etc.  But it should all be straightforward.

Comment: I have root access and the code is running on java 11. it running Linux

Comment: If you use jmh maven or gradle plugin, then it builds an uber jar. Just throw this jar to the server and run it via `java -jar`

Comment: Read what the above has said. Since you are into jmh, I guess you already know what `java/javac/classpath` is, right? If you do, this is easy to achieve.